# How can we increase the tail of the arrow in Plotly?

Tags: plotly

How can I **increase the tail of the arrow in Plotly**  so that the text, here `1st Lockdown,2nd Lockdown,3rd Lockdown and 4th Lockdown`  written is distinguishable and doesn't come in between the Line Chart?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the update_annotations method:
https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/

```
fig.update_annotations(dict(
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            showarrow=True,
            arrowhead=7,
            ax=0,
            ay=-40
))
```

For the parameter, **ay** you can try different values: -100, -150, -200, etc and you will get results like below.
[image]

You can tune the position further as you want.